# SQLite binding blob in C is terminated early

Tags: c, sqlite

I have a png file that is to be stored in a database, however, even when passing a length to `sqlite3_bind_blob()` it stops filling in the value at the first nul character.

Here's the code in question:

```
fseek(file,0xC,SEEK_CUR); // Skip to 12 (0xC) and read everything (It's a raw png file)
char content[size-0xC];
fread(content,1,size-0xC,file);

sqlite3_bind_int(inserticonstmt,1,id);
sqlite3_bind_blob(inserticonstmt,2,content,size-0xC,SQLITE_STATIC);
sqlite3_step(inserticonstmt);
sqlite3_clear_bindings(inserticonstmt);
sqlite3_reset(inserticonstmt);
```

Any ideas?

**Edit:** It looks like, while the database is in fact storing the whole blob, it's not returning it from the CLI interface

Comment: What is the value of `size`? And the file you are reading from is opened in binary mode?

Comment: size changes depending on what the program reads, but suffice to say it's `0xC` larger than the contents of the PNG. C's `fopen()` doesn't distinguish between "Binary mode" until you start reading from it, which, while using `fread()` it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sqlite cli interface has a bug where it parses blobs as strings and stops printing them early, including if it's told to send output to a file.